# How do you prevent text from moving when the user resizes the window?

Tags: html, css, text, resize

When I resize the browser window, the text moves around as well. Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Here's what I'm working on:

```
nav {
   float:left;
   background-color: #b6d433;
   width:100vw;
   text-align: center;
   position:absolute;
   margin-top: 150px;
   z-index: -1;
   overflow: hidden;
 }

ul {
    list-style: none;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left:30pt;

}
```

Comment: float and position don't work together very well.Coming to your question, I did not get ` the text moves around as well`. It will be helpful if you can tell in a detail or add a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a definite width with a non-responsive unit such as 'px', instead of 'vw'. But be informed that this will lead to a non-responsive UI behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried CSS Grid or/ and Flex.